# jquery slidebox malfunction on Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, slider

starting from some weeks ago after a new Firefox release, a slidebox based on jquery I'm using on my blog started flapping when called scrolling down the page. I upgraded first the jquery script from 1.7.2 to 1.10.0 but without benefit, when I scroll down the page and the slidebox is called it irritatingly starts flapping for a fist of seconds, then it stops on the wrong position, almost complete out but not at all.

Here is the code i'm using:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var distanceTop = $('#last').offset().top - $(window).height();

        if  ($(window).scrollTop() > distanceTop)
            $('#slidebox').animate({'right':'0px'},300);
        else
            $('#slidebox').stop(true).animate({'right':'-430px'},100);
    });

    $('#slidebox .close').bind('click',function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
```

...and here is the CSS:

```
#slidebox{
width:280px;
height:100px;
padding:10px;
background-color:#abc057;
border-top:3px solid #191919;
position:fixed;
bottom:0px;
right:-430px;
-moz-box-shadow:-2px 0px 5px #aaa;
-webkit-box-shadow:-2px 0px 5px #aaa;
box-shadow:-2px 0px 5px #aaa;
}

#slidebox p, a.more{
font-size:11px;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
letter-spacing:1px;
color:#555;
}
a.more{
cursor:pointer;
color:#E28409;
}
a.more:hover{
text-decoration:underline;
}
#slidebox h2{
color:#E28409;
font-size:18px;
margin:10px 20px 10px 0px;
}

a.close{
background:transparent    url(http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/EndPageSlideOutBox/images/close.gif) no-repeat top left;
width:13px;
height:13px;
position:absolute;
cursor:pointer;
top:10px;
right:10px;
}
a.close:hover{
background-position:0px -13px;
}
```

Does anyone has an idea how to figure out it?

Thanx!

Comment: Do you have any html? And could you set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for us?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not very good with coding....how can I help you in another way? Is it allowed here to post the link to my blog or is it considered spam?

Comment: Is it working something like this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aR56Z/23/)?

Comment: Yeah....the glitch you reproduced is pretty similar. On my blog the box flaps slower but the problem is the same. How can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seem to occur when you're animating the `slidebox` with reference to the right side. If you change your code to reference `left` instead, the shake disappears.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aR56Z/63/)

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() > distanceTop)
    $('#slidebox').animate({'left':'160px'},500);
else
    $('#slidebox').stop(true).animate({'left':'1500px'},500);
```

Of course you'll have to change the values so that it matches your page.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion! I just tried it changing the direction and indeed from left the flipping disappear. Anyway changing right to left on the code you quoted is not enough: strangely scrolling the page from the top after few lines the box shift quickly from right disappearing on the left of the screen than it appears at the "right" point on the left when I reach tag on the code.

Comment: Ok, I got it :) I forgot to change the CSS! Now it works from the right side without flapping ;) Thank you dude !!!